# Should I comply to rewrite my current project?

Tags: software-industry, japan

A continuation of [my previous issue (Please ignore the long-winded rant and just read my edit).](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/185249/boss-insists-that-i-can-do-the-project-alone-even-though-i-am-unqualified-for-th/) I will try not to rant too much this time.

So after a very long time ignoring my request, my manager, M finally responded. Unfortunately, he **did not hire anyone new**, but only **re-assign the senior contractor**, S to my current project.

**The problem:** After looking at our current code-base, S told M that I **focused too much on maintainability and security** (which I'll just pretend that he didn't say), and that **the language I and my former colleague T chose is too difficult** (I mean, it's just JavaScript, IMO not that hard). From those points, S asked if I could **re-write the project in an easier language**, in particular, either PHP or Python. Not only that, from my conversation with S, he does not know much about programming patterns either.

My initial thoughts was that he's out of his mind. While the project itself is quite simple, **it took us a lot of time to write** (more than a year), so re-writing it would not take a short time either. I'm also **not fluent in either PHP or Python**, so the time it takes to re-write would be much longer.

However, on the other hand, though nothing is concrete yet, I'm **going to leave the company on the end of August or September** (my company does not know of this). So for the most part, **only S will continue working on this project**. For now, I have told him to study about MVC, he needs to at least know that to work on our current project whether I rewrite or not, although I don't know how that would turn out. I will also try to add as much documents and Japanese instructions as possible moving forward, but **I fear those wouldn't be enough**.

All in all, I don't know which direction to move forward anymore. From the very start of the project, M flat out told us that **he will not interfere with our tech choices**, as he also did not know much about those, consulting with him on this now holds little meaning.

Should I just rewrite the entire project from scratch?

**Edit**: After a long discussion with S, I managed to convinced him to try learning JS (although whether or not he sticks to that is questionable). I will also spend time adding more documents and writing more instructions, which turns out to be a lot more troublesome than I thought. In particular, most NodeJS libraries do not have docs in Japanese. At most, there would only be some blog post about a certain aspect of the library. Some obscure library won't even have that. But that's another problem altogether.

Comment: Just to distil this whole question down, is the question: "Should I do what my boss has asked me to do?"

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It is not. Again, my manager has expressed that he would not involve in anything technical, he has little to no knowledge on the subject. This only involves me and the senior.

Comment: You need to be clearer about who is asking you to rewrite it. Because the way you've written it, it sounds like your manager has asked you. "From those points, he asked if I could re-write the project in an easier language, in particular, either PHP or Python. Not only that, from my conversation with S, he does not know much about programming patterns either."

Comment: Noted. I will edit the question. That "he" there refers to the senior.

Comment: What are the normal notice periods where you live? Is it normal that nobody knows you are leaving in 6 weeks? When would they normally know?

Comment: From what I understand, at least for this company, the notice period is 4 weeks. So there is still some time until I have to disclose this to them.

Comment: Gregory, the last 20 years my job was _not_ to do what my boss tells me to do. If I didn’t know better than my boss how to do my job, I wouldn’t have been hired.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's a nice story. Most people would get fired for going against their bosses wishes. But it's great that you have a really functional working relationship with your boss!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be leaving in a timeframe that makes it absolutely impossible to rewrite any app.

But you don't want to hint at leaving before giving notice (which is perfectly fine and normally recommended here).

You also have nothing to gain by putting up a fight or arguing about whether the app should be rewritten. While rewriting it might scratch your personal ego a bit, if the company deems it necessary and worth paying for, then it will be so.

So what to do? Well, the easiest way out I see is this: Document all known use cases with test data.

- That will take a few weeks if you do it thouroughly
- It will prove to your manager that your current version of the app is indeed working as it should (no matter what others say about it)
- It will be a very good guideline and test scenario for anybody redeveloping the app (and a big blocker for them claiming theirs is better, when in fact it's not).
- You might find bugs to fix (since the your app is running at least as long as the rewrite takes)

This leaves a good documentation for whoever needs to rewrite this app. It's not dodging any questions or making it diffuclt for anybody. It is actually helpful, either way. Even if you stay and they don't rewrite the app, because sopmething totally unexpected happened, it's still good documentation to have, because those testcases are the basic functionality that has to be tested anyway with each new release, rewrite or not.

If anyone asks why you are doing that and not coding the new app, just tell them that you need to make a plan, come up with a timeframe and you can only do this when you know all the parts of the old app.

Answer (score 3):

You could tell your manager what I would tell them.

One, if you hired a senior contractor for a JavaScript job, and they can’t read or write JavaScript, then you change the contractor, not the language.

Two, if you hire me and pay me every hour, I will gladly rewrite your code from JavaScript to Python to php to C++ and back to JavaScript, putting lots of money in my pocket without any benefit to you.

Three, that if your contractor complains about too much maintainability and security, the company will have a nightmare on its hand in two years time at most. And that this attitude can cost them millions if they have a serious breach where customers lose money.

OR you can look at it in a totally different way. Your company making stupid decisions is their problem, their money, not yours. So you take this as an opportunity to learn a new programming language while getting paid for it. Since you leave in a few months, you will obviously NOT finish that translation, but that is their problem. However, you should be able to learn a new language in that time, which can only benefit you.

Answer (score 2):

Your manager said they don't want to get involved in technical decision making. That's fine.

But at the end of the day, they are responsible for the project.

You should probably get together with the senior contractor and agree on what the pros and cons are for each option. Then when you have it all sorted, you organise a meeting with your manager to discuss which makes most sense from a business perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just rewrite the entire project from scratch?

You are leaving in a month or two. So in the meantime, you do whatever your manager tells you to do.

Tell your manager that you are being asked to rewrite the project, that you think it's a bad idea, and why. Omit the part about your leaving. Your manager then gets to make the decision and live with the results.

If you manager tells you to do it anyway, then you do it to the best of your ability within the time you have remaining.